# При загрузке страницы отображается пустая страница

Tags: apache, php

У меня с одним сайтом возникла такая проблема, захожу на сайт начинаю переходить по ссылкам - бывает страница отображается нормально, а бывает открывается просто белая страница (пустая), если нажать Ctrl+U, чтобы посмотреть HTML код, то там просто пусто. И иногда приходиться нажимать несколько раз F5, чтобы страница отобразилась. Смотрю логи сервера Apache - но там пусто, эта ошибка никак не отображается в логах. Причем сервер, где лежит сайт очень мощный (Топовый проц Core i7 + 32GB RAM DDR3 2400Mhz) Что мне делать? Как избавиться от такого глюка?

**UPD:** Вывод ошибок включен в файле php.ini. Но что самое интересное, что даже когда сервер выдает пустую страницу, то HTTP ответ сервера вот такой:

```
Request URL:http://travianx5.ru/dorf2.php
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:t3l=1; PHPSESSID=66m7fqbmi75kvaadtm2v8mhn17; COOKUSR=spoilt
Host:travianx5.ru
Referer:http://travianx5.ru/spieler.php?uid=6
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 29 Jan 2014 14:14:37 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1
```

То есть типа все ОК, но как такое может быть? В логах тоже тишина, нет 500ой ошибки, только Warning'и...

Вот лог ошибок сервера Апач за сегодняшнее число:

```
    PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '22_0.tpl' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/Templates/Build/22.tpl on line 9, referer: http://travianx5.ru/dorf2.php

    [Wed Jan 29 04:16:34.137593 2014] [:error] [pid 3276] [client 192.168.1.1:54750] PHP Warning:  unlink(GameEngine/Prevention/market.txt): No such file or directory in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 991, referer: http://travianx5.ru/dorf2.php

[Wed Jan 29 09:28:04.700181 2014] [:error] [pid 4225] [client 188.235.65.219:53207] PHP Warning:  unlink(GameEngine/Prevention/cleardeleting.txt): No such file or directory in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 457, referer: http://travianx5.ru/dorf1.php

[Wed Jan 29 11:38:05.420588 2014] [core:error] [pid 4500] [client 86.57.255.92:20043] AH00126: Invalid URI in request \xa3{(i\xc0\xb2hy\xa4\x84\xba\bq/\b7\x0c\xfcV\xbe
```

---

Вот файл .htaccess, который лежит в корне сайта:

```
<Files "*.tpl">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Скорее всего да, все проходит через этот файл:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    if(!isset($_POST['ft'])){
    $_POST = @array_map(array($database->connection, 'real_escape_string'), $_POST);
    $_POST = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $_POST);
    }
}

$rsargs=$_GET['rsargs'];
$_GET = array_map(array($database->connection, 'real_escape_string'), $_GET);
$_GET = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $_GET);

$_GET['rsargs']=$rsargs;
$_COOKIE = array_map(array($database->connection, 'real_escape_string'), $_COOKIE);
$_COOKIE = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $_COOKIE);
?>
```

Comment: Content-Length:0 - ну как бы намекает, что вывод и не начинается, попробуйте включить вывод всех ошибок в броузер (но лучше в лог конечно, если сайт посещается) И вы пишите про Warning'и, может приведете, вдруг народ что интересное увидит

Comment: Обновил вопрос, добавил логи сервера Апач...

Comment: Странно, но не работает ваш запрет:

<Files "*.tpl">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

Файлы доступны извне
На моем сайте при попытке доступа к файлам с запрещенными таким образом расширением .inc выдает 403 ошибку, а у вас исходный код

Comment: http://travianx5.ru/Templates/ перейдите по ссылке, я думаю это не то, что должны видеть все. Исправляется, как я писал ниже в коменнтах строкой -Indexes в .htaccess попробуйте!

Comment: да надо вообще туда из браузера запретить ходить напрямую :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Т.е. все прочли лог и ничего не заметили?

```
[Wed Jan 29 04:16:34.137593 2014] [:error] [pid 3276] [client 192.168.1.1:54750] PHP Warning:  unlink(GameEngine/Prevention/market.txt): No such file or directory in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 991, referer: http://travianx5.ru/dorf2.php
```

Comment: То есть Вы думаете, что в этом и есть вся причина?

Comment: PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '22_0.tpl' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/Templates/Build/22.tpl on line 9, referer: http://travianx5.ru/dorf2.php

а тут показывает что не может подключить шаблон. Проверяйте наличие файлов.

Comment: Файл "22_0.tpl" у меня есть в проекте, сейчас проверю пути...

Comment: [**unlink**][1] - Удаляет файл


  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unlink.php

Comment: Файлов Templates/Build/22_0.tpl и GameEngine/Prevention/market.txt у вас на данный момент не существует. Если они автоматически создаются и удаляются, то ищите проблему в скриптах, но так как этот скрипт игры не ваш, то возможно этот баг к разработчику (если это конечно не вы напортачили ну или злобные "хацкеры" :) )

Answer (score 2):

Дописать логирование в сам движок сайта. Чтобы отслеживать в каких местах валится система.

Comment: А конкретнее, что-то можете посоветовать? Как можно отдебажить такую проблему?

Comment: Попробуйте для начала просмотреть код который должен запуститься на странице которая у Вас вылезла пустая. Скорее всего код валится с ошибкой до вывода html и у Вас отключен вывод ошибок. Включите отображение ошибок командой error_reporting(E_ALL); в самом верху index.php но ниже(если присутствует) строки session_start();. Если ошибка в коде, Вам выведет всю информацию почему не выводится страница.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста...

Comment: Посмотрел. Включите принудительно вывод ошибок error_reporting(E_ALL); на страницу dorf2.php и скопируйте сюда то что выдаст.

Comment: Добавил, но пока ничего не выдает!

Answer (score 2):

В php.ini пропиши

```
display_errors on
```

и

```
error_reporting = 2147483647
```